# Hyper-V uninstall mvEthernet Switch deleted and main ethernet adapter does not have ip

Tags: networking, windows-10, hyper-v

I did following thing.

1. Installed Hyper-v quite long ago.
2. When Hyper-V created there is one vEthernet switch get created and that hold ip address information that previously held by main adapter.

Now I have uninstalled Hyper-V by disabling the feature.
1. Not able to connect that machine any more.
2. It seems that machine lost ip address.

What should be done ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hyper-V adds another layer and takes over the NIC with a virtual switch.  When you removed Hyper-V, the virtual switch went with it.  Those settings, TCP/IP address, gateway, etc need to be re-added back to your physical NIC.

In most cases, during the installation, Hyper-V will move the IP settings to the virtual switch.  However, when you remove the Hyper-V role, it does not move those IP settings back.

Basically, it's like you've removed the old NIC (Hyper-V virtual switch), and stuck in a new one (actual physical NIC) and now you need to configure it.

Comment: Yes. I already resolved the problem. What you have said is correct and my assumption is same and along with that my machine has issue with Windows update so when hyper-v get removed it goes for windows update screen and at that screen it stuck . So I have to start once in safe mode then it is working as expected. Still i have to configure physical NIC.